# Why is PHP not including my file when it clearly exists?

Tags: php, include

Here is the exact problem.  I have an autoload function set up with a piece of code that looks like this:

```
if(file_exists($class_file))
{
    include($class_file);
    return true;
}
```

However, when `$class_file` is set to a certain value, I get an include error:

```
Error String: include(includes/php/utilities/calendar_event_html.utility.php)
[function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It works fine for other files and when I step through this code with a debugger it is clear that PHP believes the file exists, but it seems that `include` does not.  Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps PHP doesn't have permissions to access this file?

Comment: @ApoY2k Well, as you can see in the error, the contents are `includes/php/utilities/calendar_event_html.utility.php`, but it works just fine with something like `includes/php/utilities/calendar_header_html.utility.php` - both of which must exist since I'm doing `file_exists` beforehand.

Comment: Is the above code _really_ the same as the one you're using in your application? If not, does the include happen in an other file than the file_exists?

Comment: @halfdan yes, it's really the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the manual:

```
Note: The check is done using the real UID/GID instead of the effective one.
```

This means that the file may exist, but it's possible that it is not accessible by the UID/GID your PHP instance is running with. I suggest you check the permissions to that file.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: I'm on Windows so I didn't think permissions would be a problem (they never have been before), but I copied this particular file using Cygwin - I wonder if it changed the permissions of the file when I did that...

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour on a different machine?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I did have some similar problems with some javascript files that I copied using Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this bit of debugging code:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo get_include_path();
echo "</pre>";
```

[function.get-include-path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php)

This will return your current include path, and you can compare it with your $class_file string.